# PDF page size with wider image

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

I am processing PDF files with PDF Box and insert text objects according to the given coordinates on the pages. The coordinates I get are top-left based and I find the media box of the page, then calculate the position of the text. However there are some PDF images (they're scanned) which the text I inserted does not stand on the correct location, like the size of the page is much bigger than I get with media box.

```
// getX-Y returns the coordinates that the text should be inserted
// getSize returns the text height
void write(PDDocument doc, PDPage page, PDPageContentStream cs) {
    PDRectangle rect = page.findMediaBox();
    cs.moveTextPositionByAmount(this.getX(), height-this.getY()-getSize());
}
```

The dimensions retreieved from media box are `595.2 x 841.92`. For a given text location `300x420`, I expect this text to be inserted in the middle of the page. However it is inserted way too down and left of the page. When I open the document with Acrobat Reader and copy the page as image (since it's scanned) I see that the image dimensions are `2480 x 3508`. The location of the inserted text would make sense if the page dimensions were in that size.

I feel like pdf page size is changed according to the content it has, but why don't I get those dimensions as the page size and still getting something like `595.2 x 841.92` instead? Should I process every image on the page and find the true dimensions? What am I missing here?

Edit:
[Sample PDF Document](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/93180858/0006-sun1-4.pdf)

Edit:
This is the code part that I get `PDPageContentStream`:

```
PDDocument doc = null;
doc = PDDocument.load(inputFile);
List <?> allPages = doc.getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages();
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    PDFObject obj = (PDFObject) list.get(i);
    for (int j = 0; j < allPages.size(); j++) {
        PDPage page = (PDPage) allPages.get(j);
        PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(doc, page, true, true);
        obj.write(doc, page, contentStream);
        if ("F".equalsIgnoreCase(obj.getPageType())) {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ca you supply a sample pdf?

Comment: @mkl https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/93180858/0006-sun1-4.pdf

Comment: How do you get that `PDPageContentStream`? Especially, have you made sure that the default user space coordinate system is still in use or may it be transformed? Furthermore, what is `height`? It would make sense to use `rect.getUpperRightY()` (for the default user space coordinate system).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the OP did not post all relevant code. Thus, this answer is partially based on assumptions, especially that he created his `PDPageContentStream` **without** making sure that the default user space coordinate system is still in use at the position where he adds new operations.

### The sample document

The content stream of the first page starts like this:

```
0.24000 0 0 0.24000 0 0 cm
q
2480 0 0 3508 0 0 cm
/Im5 Do
Q
```

Thus, it first scales the user space coordinate system by `.24`, pushes the graphics state, scales the coordinate system by `2480` (x direction) and `3508` (y direction), draws an image, and eventually restores the graphics state.

Thus, thereafter the user space coordinate system is still scaled by `.24`. So coordinates given in the following operations are subject to that factor.

Immediately following are text objects, e.g. this:

```
BT
1 0 0 rg
/F0 25 Tf
400 794.9199829102 Td
(JFE14006) Tj
ET
```

I assume this is one of the objects added by the OP not taking the non-default user space coordinate system into account as the coordinates and font size seem adequate for the default user space coordinate system.

(BTW, the referred-to font is not defined in the resources dictionary of the page.)

### Solution 1

As the user space coordinate system at the insertion point is scaled by .24, you can counter-scale your own coordinates and sizes (i.e. divide them by .24).

E.g. to draw the text "MIDDLE" at the given  given text location 300x420 (origin in the upper-left) using a font of size 10, you could do:

```
PDDocument document = PDDocument.load("0006-sun1-4.pdf");
List<PDPage> allPages = document.getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages();
PDPage firstPage = allPages.get(0);
PDRectangle pageSize = firstPage.findMediaBox();

PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(document, firstPage, true, true);
contentStream.setStrokingColor(Color.red);
contentStream.beginText();
contentStream.moveTextPositionByAmount(300/.24f, (pageSize.getUpperRightY() - 420 - 10)/.24f);
contentStream.setFont(PDType1Font.HELVETICA_BOLD, 10/.24f);
contentStream.drawString("MIDDLE");
contentStream.endText();
contentStream.close();

document.save("0006-sun1-4-scaledAdd.pdf");
document.close();
```

This solution is not optimal, though:

- as soon as you have another source document (e.g. an updated form), the content stream at the insertion point might have a differently scaled coordinate system;
- other states of the graphics drawing engine might also not be in their default state expected by you.

Thus:

### Solution 2

You can revert all changes to the graphics state by enclosing the existing content stream with a **q** (save graphics state) and **Q** (restore graphics state) operator pair.

E.g. as above to draw the text "MIDDLE" at the given  given text location 300x420 (origin in the upper-left) using a font of size 10, you could do:

```
PDDocument document = PDDocument.load("0006-sun1-4.pdf");
List<PDPage> allPages = document.getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages();
PDPage firstPage = allPages.get(0);
PDRectangle pageSize = firstPage.findMediaBox();

PDStream contents = firstPage.getContents();  
PDFStreamParser parser = new PDFStreamParser(contents.getStream()); 
parser.parse();
List<Object> tokens = parser.getTokens();
tokens.add(0, PDFOperator.getOperator("q"));
tokens.add(PDFOperator.getOperator("Q"));
PDStream updatedStream = new PDStream(document);  
OutputStream out = updatedStream.createOutputStream();  
ContentStreamWriter tokenWriter = new ContentStreamWriter(out);  
tokenWriter.writeTokens(tokens);  
firstPage.setContents(updatedStream);

PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(document, firstPage, true, true);
contentStream.setStrokingColor(Color.red);
contentStream.beginText();
contentStream.moveTextPositionByAmount(300, pageSize.getUpperRightY() - 420 - 10);
contentStream.setFont(PDType1Font.HELVETICA_BOLD, 10);
contentStream.drawString("MIDDLE");
contentStream.endText();
contentStream.close();

document.save("0006-sun1-4-restoredAdd.pdf");
document.close();
```

(Parsing and rewriting the existing stream is not exactly good style resource-wise but not a real issue in case of pages which essentially only draw an image.)

[image: Screenshot of result]

Comment: Thank you! I assume that there is no programmatic way to get the scale factor of the non-default user space since you haven't mentioned?

Comment: *I assume that there is no programmatic way to get the scale factor of the non-default user space* - You can do it using an instance of `PDFStreamEngine` or some descendant class to execute the stream operations keeping track of the graphics state and looking at its final current transformation matrix value. But as mentioned above, *other states of the graphics drawing engine might also not be in their default state* and you'd have to take them into account, too. Enveloping the existing stream in **q** .. **Q**, therefore, is the foolproof way, you get a graphics state at default values.

Comment: This is a very well prepared answer, solved my problem. Thank you very much. I'm just asking for curiosity: Is leaving the user space scaled like that (.24 factor) an error? I've tried with 5 different scanners, only one of them creating the PDF files like that.

Comment: It is not an error. Many pdf creators, though, use simple sections enveloped by **q** .. **Q** top be able to put them together in any order they like. Thus, often you find default settings at the end of a content stream.